# Put html response image in JFrame

Tags: java, html, swing

I have the following html that i would like to use to display a google streetview. The HTML was been tested and works to return a streetview however I am not sure how to set the %%lat%% and %%long%% wildcard values and I am not sure how to retrieve the streetview and put it in a `JFrame` or `JOptionPane`. HTML as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(%%lat%%, %%lon%%);
        var panoramaOptions = {
            position: markerPosition,
            pov: {
                heading: 165,
                pitch: 0,
                zoom: 1
            }
        };
        var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
        myPano.setVisible(false);
        new google.maps.Marker({map: myPano, position: markerPosition, title: 'Feature'});

        var changeImage = function(){
            var image = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=44.414382,11.013988&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76";
            document.getElementById("pano").innerHTML = "<img src='" + image + "' style='width:100%;height:100%'>"; 
        }
        // add a variable that gets set when the position_changed handler gets fired off
        var positionDidChange = false;
        var newPov = {};
        var listenerHandle = google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, 'position_changed', function () {
            positionDidChange = true;
            google.maps.event.removeListener(listenerHandle);
            newPov.heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(myPano.getPosition(), markerPosition);
            newPov.pitch = 0;
            newPov.zoom = 1;
            myPano.setPov(newPov); myPano.setVisible(true);
        });

        // add a function that gets fired off to see if the position did change so that the user does not wait forever
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!positionDidChange) {
                changeImage();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="pano" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;      text-align: center"> LOADING STREET VIEW...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

that I would like to get the response from when I am in the following method:

```
    @Override
protected void onMouseDown(MouseButton button,
                           KeyModifier keyModifier,
                           int mouseX,
                           int mouseY) {
    try {
        if (MouseButton.LEFT.equals(button)) {

            FeatureWrapper closestStationOrSpanFw = SelectionUtil.getClosestSpanOrStation(toMapPoint(mouseX, mouseY));
            if (closestStationOrSpanFw != null) {
                IGeometry shape = closestStationOrSpanFw.getIFeature().getShapeCopy();
                IPoint point = null;
                if (shape instanceof IPoint) {
                    point = (IPoint) shape;
                    double lat = point.getY();
                    double lon = point.getX();
                    ....
```

Comment: You could place a mark in the `HTML` template and use `String#replace` or similar functionality.

Comment: Yes that would definitely work for replacing the lat/long placeholders thanks. my real challenge is retrieving the response in such a way that I can display it

Comment: Swing doesn't really do this well.  SwingLabs (SwingX-WS?) has an example using OpenStreet.  Google doesn't want you doing what you're trying to do outside of Web browser, and Swing's browser support is rather limited (and out of date).  JavaFX might be a better option, but I've never tried

Comment: You do realize that [Google Maps provides an API](https://developers.google.com/maps/), right?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson the Google StreetView API page only provides information on how to build a url to display a streetview image. I would like to get an actual streetview that I can pan around... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro

Comment: Then you're probably better off using the `WebView` of Java-FX rather than any Swing component.  The Swing HTML components do not support JS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll have much success getting your `HTML` to work in Swing, it's HTML/web support is pretty dated.  A solution might be to use the `WebView` from Java-FX.

However, if all you want to do is display the image, you can do something like...

[image: StreetView]

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10");
        try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, I might be temptered to write a method which takes the parameters and generates the `URL`

```
protected static final String BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&";

public BufferedImage getStreetView(double lat, double log, double fov, double heading, double pitch) throws IOException {

    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("&");
    sj.add(BASE_URL);
    sj.add("location=" + Double.toString(lat) + "," + Double.toString(log));
    sj.add("fov=" + Double.toString(fov));
    sj.add("heading=" + Double.toString(heading));
    sj.add("pitch=" + Double.toString(pitch));

    BufferedImage img = null;
    URL url = new URL(sj.toString());
    try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
        img = ImageIO.read(is);
    }

    return img;
}
```

Or better, some kind of builder

Then you could just call it using something like...

```
BufferedImage img = getStreetView(40.720032, -73.988354, 90d, 235d, 10d);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
```

Comment: yes while i appreciate your help and work, I actually already have the streetview image working. My goal is to expand this functionality to the full streetview :( +1 helpful

Comment: @peggy While it might be possible to reverse engineer the Google JavaScript and get this to work in pure Swing, I doubt it would worth effort. The web view component might be better idea